# Is it possible to create a dynamic map in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, atlas, qgis2web, choropleth

My table looks like this:

[image]

I’ve already done a Choropleth map with the first attribute of my table.

[image]

I would like to do the same Choropleth map with the rest of my attributes. I can’t replicate it manually because I have lots of attributes in my table.

Is there any possible way I could make a dynamic map where I select the category and the map gets coloured by that category? Qgis2web, Atlas?

Comment: You picture is a Choropleth map not a heat map https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choropleth_map vs Heatmap https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/creating_heatmaps.html

Comment: maybe you can edit your question and not use the phrase "heatmap", then it is easier to answer

Comment: You are right, i'm going to change it

Comment: Welcome @SofiaR ! How do you want to select the category in the map? Splitting fields into related tables is an option?

Comment: Thank you @GabrielDeLuca! Yes, it's a possible option.
My table has 43 categories. I Just need the easiest way to make a choropleth map with all the categories. I wouldn't like to duplicate and style the layer for all of 43 categories. I am searching for a most convinient way to do it in order to export it in Qgis2web or Atlas or another.

Answer (score 3):

You can create multiple styles per layer, and switch between them. In the `Layer Styling` panel, click on the `Style Manager` icon, and then use the + button to add each style.

[image: The Style Manager in the Layer Styling panel]

Each different style that you add can use a categorized (or graduated) renderer, each one categorizing on a different one of your fields. You can then switch between them by selecting the appropriate style in the Style Manager.

Comment: That is very useful, i didn’t know it was possible.
Do you know if I can export that map with multiple styles using Qgis2web? I want users to be able to switch between the different categories. I’ve tried but i just couldn’t do it. My intuition is that i would have to replicate the layer multiple times and add a different style to each one.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not supported in qgis2web. A way to achieve it would be to duplicate your whole layer for each catogorization, and apply each of the different categorized styles to those layers. That should export to qgis2web.